# two dimension list with dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I try to make two dimension list with dictionary.
I would like to make it, every hours, left times, right times.

1 am, ActionEnum.Left = 10, ActionEnum.Right = 20 
2 am, ActionEnum.Left = 40, ActionEnum.Right = 50 
3 am, ActionEnum.Left = 60, ActionEnum.Right = 70 
4 am, ActionEnum.Left = 30, ActionEnum.Right = 40

...

```
Dictionary<ActionEnum, int> indexer1 = new Dictionary<ActionEnum, int>();
ActionEnum[] values = (ActionEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ActionEnum));
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    indexer1.Add(values[i], i);
}

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<ActionEnum, int>> indexer2 = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<ActionEnum, int>>(); 
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    indexer2.Add(i, indexer1);
}


indexer2[0][ActionEnum.Left] = 10; indexer2[0][ActionEnum.Right] = 20;
indexer2[1][ActionEnum.Left] = 40; indexer2[1][ActionEnum.Right] = 50;
indexer2[2][ActionEnum.Left] = 60; indexer2[2][ActionEnum.Right] = 70;
indexer2[3][ActionEnum.Left] = 30; indexer2[3][ActionEnum.Right] = 40;

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(indexer2[i][(ActionEnum)j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

It seems to work, 
 but when I have assigned values, the dictonary holds with last values. 
 Would you give me some help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because indexer1 is added to indexer2 by reference. you need to create new dictionary each time you want to add it to another dictionary. use `new` keyword to create new dictionary. change your second loop to this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    indexer2.Add(i, new Dictionary<ActionEnum, int>(indexer1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. M.kazem, it work as it is. I can say more thanks.